# How can I update BASH

Tags: bash, centos, security, upgrade, shellshock

How can I update BASH?
I noticed that there are version 4.2.45

```
env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"
this is a test

cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 5.11 (Final)

rpm -q bash
bash-3.2-33.el5_11.4

yum update bash
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

Comment: You understand that your results indicate you're not vulnerable right?

Comment: Lol, like he said, if it doesn't return `vulnerable` then your are not vulnerable. If you still want to update you can compile bash via source.

Comment: it doesn't return vulnerable, but I saw that the version that is installed on server is much older. But OK, if that's not a problem if the server is not vulnerable.

Answer (score 2):

You have the most updated bash version for `CentOS 5.11`.  Version `bash-4.2.45-5.el7_0.4` is for `CentOS 7.X`  [This RedHat page](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2014-1306.html) lists the latest bash versions per OS.